# Gradle не собирает проект.

Tags: android, gradle, сборка, build

При сборке проекта в Intelij Idea ошибка:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Could not expand ZIP '/home/vlad/.android/build-cache/d530ca9633922ad31329b7ee75caf55107c69645/output/jars/classes.jar'.

Comment: Попробуйте `File-Invalidate cache and restart`

Comment: Попробвал. не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему переносом проекта в домашнюю директорию ubuntu